# How to compile Sass/SCSS in the browser without needing a server-side to run the compiler?

Tags: javascript, sass, compilation, frontend

OK I had no idea this was so complicated but after several hours of searching and testing I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I simply want to compile a SASS/SCSS string **in the browser** without calling a server-based compiler. In other words, I want to import a Sass library and then pass a SCSS string into a function, which would return a compiled CSS result.

*Please note that I understand this is not a good practice for production websites - my need is only for testing, to save time and avoid spinning up a server to test basic HTML files. Answers that say "Don't do this for performance reasons" will be downvoted, because in this instance performance is not a concern.*

Requiring NodeJS or other server-side software is not acceptable, nor are binaries that must be run on the source SCSS code to compile it.

I have tried using the [SASS library from CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/sass.js/0.9.2) but inevitably hitting brick walls.
When attempting this, the following code doesn't work. It simply returns nothing and never calls the callback function.  Seems the `compile` function requires a filename, but I simply want to pass a string.

The NPM version has a bunch of dependencies so it would be difficult to get it to run in the browser.

What I have tried:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/sass.js/0.9.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.9.2/sass.worker.js"></script>
<script>
    
    const scss_to_compile = `
        .element1 {
            color: red;
        }`;

    Sass.compile(scss_to_compile, (result) => { console.log(result); });
    // The callback never executes.
</script>
```

UPDATE: a solution is to use the [Medialize fork of Sass.JS](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js), which works, but may be old having no updates since 2019...

Comment: https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#compiling-strings according to this it takes a string.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#using-the-synchronous-api-in-the-browser):

> It is possible - but *not recommended* to use Sass.js in the main EventLoop by loading `dist/sass.sync.js`

Also, it can accept a string for compilation.

Here's a working example:

```js
const scss_to_compile = `
        .element1 {
            color: red;
        }`;

Sass.compile(scss_to_compile, (result) => {
  console.log(result.text);
});

const scss_with_var = '$someVar: 123px; .some-selector { width: $someVar; }';

Sass.compile(scss_with_var, (result) => {
  console.log(result.text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.11.1/sass.sync.min.js"></script>
```

Also, FYI, the above example does not work with v0.9.2, so I would suggest using the latest version.